# Unable to read a barcode using apache camel

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, barcode

Hi i have tried to read a barcode from image using below code but i am unable to read the file as it contains multiple barcodes. Is there any work around for this?

```
@GetMapping(value = "OCR/Apachecamel")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get result from Barcode Apachecamel library")
    public BarcodeInfo GetApachecamelResult() throws Exception {
        try {
            InputStream barCodeInputStream = new FileInputStream("images/multiple.png");
            BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(
                    new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(ImageIO.read(barCodeInputStream))));
            if (bitmap.getWidth() < bitmap.getHeight()) {
                if (bitmap.isRotateSupported()) {
                    bitmap = bitmap.rotateCounterClockwise();
                }
            }
            return decode(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new BarcodeDecodingException(e);
        }
    }

    private BarcodeInfo decode(BinaryBitmap bitmap) throws BarcodeDecodingException {
        Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
        try {
            Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);
            return new BarcodeInfo(result.getText(), result.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BarcodeDecodingException(e);
        }
    }

    public static class BarcodeInfo {

        private final String text;

        private final String format;

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public String getFormat() {
            return format;
        }

        BarcodeInfo(String text, String format) {
            this.text = text;
            this.format = format;
        }
    }

    public static class BarcodeDecodingException extends Exception {
        BarcodeDecodingException(Throwable cause) {
            super(cause);
        }
    }
```

**pom.xml**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-barcode -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-barcode</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Error**
[image]

**Image enclosed [image]**

Could some one let me know is there any workaround for this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should learn [fundamentals-of-algorithms](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fundamentals-of-algorithms/) and [Java](https://www.w3schools.com/JAVA/default.asp) first then just [`TRY_HARDER`](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/DecodeHintType.html#TRY_HARDER) and use [`GenericMultipleBarcodeReader`](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/multi/GenericMultipleBarcodeReader.html) :)

```java
public class MbcPoc {

    public static void main(String... args) throws NotFoundException, IOException {
        List<BarcodeInfo> list = decodeImageWithMBC("fREyt.png");
        list.forEach(BarcodeInfo::println);
    }

    private static List<BarcodeInfo> decodeImageWithMBC(String imgPath) throws NotFoundException, IOException {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(imgPath));
        BinaryBitmap bb = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(img)));
        MultipleBarcodeReader mbReader = new GenericMultipleBarcodeReader(new MultiFormatReader());
        Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> hints = new Hashtable<>();
        hints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
        List<BarcodeInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Result result : mbReader.decodeMultiple(bb, hints)) {
            list.add(new BarcodeInfo(result.getText(), result.getBarcodeFormat().name()));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static class BarcodeInfo {
        private final String text;
        private final String format;

        BarcodeInfo(String text, String format) {
            this.text = text;
            this.format = format;
        }

        public static void println(BarcodeInfo bci) {
            System.out.println(bci.text + "/" + bci.format);
        }
    }
}
```